# IndexedSeq.last complexity

Tags: performance, scala, vector, collections

When working with indexed collections (most often [immutable Vectors](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector)) I am often using `coll.last` as what I supposed to be a convenient short-cut to `coll(coll.size-1)`. When randomly inspecting my sources, I have clicked to see the `last` implementation, and the IntelliJ IDE took me to `TraversableLike.last` implementation, which traverses all elements to eventually reach the last one.

This was a surprise to me, and I am not sure now what is the reason for this. Is `last` really implemented this way? Is there some reason preventing `last` to be implemented for `IndexedSeq` (or perhaps for `IndexedSeqLike`) efficiently?

(Scala SDK used is 2.11.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexedSeq` has constant access time for the arbitrary element. `LinearSeq` has linear time. `TraversableLike` is just common interface and you may find that it's overriden inside [`IndexedSeqOptimized`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala) trait:

> A template trait for indexed sequences of type `IndexedSeq[A]` which
>   optimizes  the implementation of several methods under the
>   assumption of fast random access.

```
def last: A = if (length > 0) this(length - 1) else super.last
```

You may also find the quick random access implementation inside [Vector.getElem](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala) - it uses a tree of arrays with high branching factor, so *usually* it's O(1) for `apply`. It doesn't use `IndexedSeqOptimized`, but it has its own overriden `last`:

```
override /*TraversableLike*/ def last: A = {
    if (isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.last")
    apply(length-1)
}
```

So it's a little mess inside Scala collections, which is very common for Scala internals. Anyway `last` on `IndexedSeq`s is O(1) *de facto*, regardless such tricky collections architecture.

The Scala collections intricacy is actually an active topic. A talk (and slides) with Scala's collection framework criticism may be found at [Paul Phillips: Scala Collections: Why Not?](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/1568/scala_collections_why_not_paul_phillips_video), and Paul Phillips is developing [his alternate version of std](https://github.com/paulp/psp-std).

Answer (score 3):

`IndexedSeq` does not override `last` (it only inherits it from `TraversableLike`) - the fact that a particular sequence supports indexed access does not necessarily make indexed lookups faster than traversals. However, such optimized implementations [are given in `IndexedSeqOptimized`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqOptimized.scala#L131), which I would expect many implementations to inherit from. In the specific case of `Vector`, [`last` is overridden explicitly in the class itself](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.scala#L196).